# Find the number of time a value appears in a column for each time period

Tags: r, dataframe, count

```
 df1 <- data.frame(x1 =
 c("b","e","f","g","a","d","c","d","h","d","i","j"), x2 = c("Aug 2017",
 "Aug 2017", "Aug 2017","Sep 2017","Sep 2017","Sep 2017","Oct
 2017","Oct 2017","Oct 2017","Nov 2017","Nov 2017","Nov 2017"), x3 =
 c(456,678,876,987,123,324,345,564,333,255,687,476))
```

[image]

From the above dataframe, I need to find the number of times a value in x1 appears for each time period in x2. In df1, the value 'd' in x1 column occurs 3 times for the months 'Sep 2017', 'Oct 2017,' 'Nov 2017'. I wanna get the value 3 as output. If 'd' occurs for every continuous month in 'x2' column, return the number of times it occurs.

[image]

For the data frame `df2`,'d' occurs in 'Oct 2017', 'Nov 2017' and 'Aug 2017', then the output should be '2' not '3'.

Comment: How about `xtabs(~ x1+x2, df2)` or `table(df$x1, df$x2)`?

Comment: Hi, if any answers have solved your question, please select one of them you more prefer as accepted by clicking the check mark next to it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
# Sys.setlocale('LC_ALL','English') # You may run this if df2$x2 prints NA
df2 <- df1 %>%
  mutate(x2 = as.yearmon(x2, format = "%b %Y")) 
res <- data.frame()
for (i in unique(df2$x1)) {
  dummy <- df2[df2$x1 == i,]
  m <- ifelse(nrow(dummy) == 1, 1, max(rle(diff(dummy$x2))$lengths) + 1)
  res <- rbind(res, c(i, m))
}
names(res) <- c("x1", "count")
res
   x1 count
1   b     1
2   e     1
3   f     1
4   g     1
5   a     1
6   d     3
7   c     1
8   h     1
9   i     1
10  j     1
```

Comment: This method cannot deal with the time range which spans two years. E.g. if I add `"Dec 2017"` and `"Jan 2018"` to `d`, the output should be 5, not 4.

Comment: @DarrenTsai I'm trying handle `%b`, but it doesn't work in my session. I need to update it after handle this stuation ...

Answer (score 1):

You could use `zoo::as.yearmon()` to convert `x2` into a monthly time class, and then `diff()` to calculate the time differences. (The differnece of two consecutive months is `1/12` in `yearmon`.) `cumsum()` is used to dertermine whether a series of times are consecutive or not.

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  mutate(x2 = zoo::as.yearmon(x2)) %>%
  group_by(x1) %>%
  arrange(x2, .by_group = TRUE) %>%
  summarise(x3 = max(rle(cumsum(c(TRUE, !near(diff(x2), 1/12))))$lengths))

# # A tibble: 10 x 2
#    x1       x3
#    <chr> <int>
#  1 a         1
#  2 b         1
#  3 c         1
#  4 d         3
#  5 e         1
#  6 f         1
#  7 g         1
#  8 h         1
#  9 i         1
# 10 j         1
```

Here I use `!near(diff(x2), 1/12)` instead of `diff(x2) != 1/12` because of the roundoff errors.